# How to deploy Django app on Google App Engine and make connection with Postgres instance?

Tags: django, postgresql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

Currently I am trying to deploy a Django app on Google App Engine(GAE). All goes well and app is deployed, but when it gets deployed, its connection with Postgres instance lost. I don't know why this happening. following is my **settings.py** file.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'dbname',
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',

    }
}
# In the flexible environment, you connect to CloudSQL using a unix socket.
# Locally, you can use the CloudSQL proxy to proxy a localhost connection
# to the instance
DATABASES['default']['HOST'] = '/cloudsql/shopnroar-175407:us-central1:snr-instance1'
if os.getenv('GAE_INSTANCE'):
    pass
else:
    DATABASES['default']['HOST'] = '100.107.126.241'
```

When i run it locally, it's making connection with google cloud Postgres as i have given ipv4 address to make connection, but as soon as i deploy it on **GAE**, following error comes while accessing database.

```
Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/cloudsql/shopnroar-175407:us-central1:snr-instance1/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

here is my **app.yaml**

```
# [START runtime]
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT SNR.wsgi

env_variables:
    # Replace user, password, database, and instance connection name with the values obtained
    # when configuring your Cloud SQL instance.
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI: >-
      postgresql+psycopg2://amad.uddin:goingtoin1122@/shopnroar?host=/cloudsql/shopnroar-175407:us-central1:snr-instance1
beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: shopnroar-175407:us-central1:snr-instance1

runtime_config:
  python_version: 2
# [END runtime]
```

Can anybody tell me how can i make connection with postgres instance after deploying django app on GAE?

Any help or suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually - forget my old answer - try turning the app.yaml values into strings, that helped me out:

```
cloud_sql_instances: 'shopnroar-175407:us-central1:snr-instance1'
```